# React Native 23.1 unexpected token (14:6)

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

This is so weird. I just created a new project which is version 23.1 and when running it in iOS it comes up with this error. Its the default code! I haven't changed anything and yet it doesn't work. My past default projects obviously worked and my current apps all still work no problem. I even tried creating the project again but it still doesn't work.

I tried creating yet another project with a different name but that didn't work either.

If nobody knows why then I'll have to post it as an issue with 23.1.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error? Need more information on the issue.

Comment: Ok I've posted a screenshot but I don't think it says a lot more. No idea why this error could be appearing in every new project I make while old projects work fine. I have one with RN 22.1 which works fine.

Comment: Whats on line 14:6 in the code?

Comment: Its just the default code when you create a project. Are you familiar with React Native btw? The line is this:  "class default extends Component {"

Comment: Yes, been using it for a while now. When you upgraded to 23.1 did you upgrade babel as well? Did you clear your RNPackager cache? Just created an RN 23.1 project and had no issues.

Comment: I didn't upgrade anything, I just created a new project. I've been doing this since version 0.14 with all my projects and no problems. I just create a new project and its created with the latest version. This is the first time there's been a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109114/discussion-between-hasen-and-zidail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write

```
export default class extends Component {
```

instead of

```
class default extends Component {
```

**Edit:**

The problem, in this case, was that `react-native init` got called with reserved keywords like `default` or `new`.

Comment: So you're saying the default code created by React Native is wrong? Then its surely an issue with React Native then.

Comment: Is your app by any chance named `default`? I just initalized it with the name `bar` and got the following index.js: https://gist.github.com/DanielMSchmidt/7ef2a16249eb306d4f05f8b3753cc856

Comment: Yes it is called 'default' although I did try with other names and it didn't work either. I tried with the name 'new' which didn't work either. I'll try with a more unique name then. Weird error.

Comment: That is exactly the problem: both are reserved keywords in Javascript (`new` since ever and `default` since ECMAScript 6). If you try something else like foo or test it will work

Comment: Yeah that was it, I created a new project with the name 'what' and it worked fine. Just my luck that the name 'new' I tried just in case was also no good. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe you should try more verbose names next time, DemoApp is in no language a reserved keyword :) Glad that it helped ;)